# NSURLConnection blows up with unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've used NSURLConnection many times in the past and it has always worked great.  Now I'm adding it to a new project, and it's blowing up every single time I try to use it.  I've reduced the code to something very, very simple and it STILL blows up.  I simply created an object derived from NSObject, and implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol.  I'm not even saving the data at all anymore.

Here's the code for the object:

```
@implementation MyTest
{
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSURL *url;
    NSURLRequest *request;
}

- (void) tryitout
{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];

    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval) 60.0];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (connection == nil)
        NSLog (@"Can't get an NSURLConnection");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog (@"Error connecting, error is %@", error);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog (@"Got a response");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog (@"Got some data");
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    NSLog (@"All done");
}
```

Then to test this, I've simply implemented this after a button press (testObject is a global variable that definitely is hanging around):

```
testObject = [[MyTest alloc] init];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [testObject tryitout];
});
```

Now, shortly after the NSURLConnection object is created (and started), I get this crash:

```
2014-12-17 10:12:17.161 TestApp[43359:18903] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10331cfd0
2014-12-17 10:12:17.163 TestApp[43359:18903] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-12-17 10:12:17.164 TestApp[43359:18903] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10331cfd0
2014-12-17 10:12:17.165 TestApp[43359:18903] (
      0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a48525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
      1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8dfade75 objc_exception_throw + 43
      2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a48812d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
      3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3e3272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
      4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3e2df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
      5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a39ee41 CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes + 81
      6   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830c15f8 _ZL13appendEscapedP10__CFStringPKS_ + 40
      7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830c1344 _ZL25initializeUserAgentStringv + 124
      8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87bc38d6 __pthread_once_handler + 65
      9   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff871a3156 _os_once + 73
      10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87bc3875 pthread_once + 57
      11  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ac71e cleanUpRequest + 105
      12  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ac469 _ZN17HTTPNetConnection19prepareTransmissionEP17HTTPNetStreamInfoP17__CoreWriteStream + 1249
      13  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ab66b _ZN13NetConnection7enqueueEPvh + 539
      14  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ab3ea _ZN17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 88
      15  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ab38d _ZThn120_N17HTTPNetStreamInfo16_streamImpl_OpenEP13CFStreamErrorPh + 13
      16  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff8307c3bc _ZN14CoreStreamBase21_streamInterface_OpenEv + 80
      17  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830ab0cd _ZN12HTTPProtocol10openStreamEv + 255
      18  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830aa474 _ZN12HTTPProtocol26useNetConnectionForRequestEP13NetConnectionP15__CFHTTPMessageh + 1750
      19  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830a9cae _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry28dispatchConnectionToProtocolEP13NetConnectionP12HTTPProtocolP18HTTPRequestMessageh + 276
      20  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830a9a6d _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry34notifyNextProtocolOfOpenConnectionEP13NetConnectionh + 301
      21  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830a6dbf _ZN24HTTPConnectionCacheEntry25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 685
      22  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830a67bc _ZN19HTTPConnectionCache34_onqueue_enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage + 178
      23  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff830a66e1 ___ZN19HTTPConnectionCache25enqueueRequestForProtocolEP12HTTPProtocolP15__CFHTTPMessage_block_invoke + 26
      24  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff8309d1dc ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 25
      25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a381a94 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
      26  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff8309d0bb _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 115
      27  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff8309cf63 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 269
      28  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff8309cd92 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
      29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3b65b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
      30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3a7c62 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
      31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3a73ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831
      32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3a6e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
      33  Foundation                          0x00007fff854dbff7 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
      34  Foundation                          0x00007fff854dbdfb __NSThread__main__ + 1318
      35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87bc2899 _pthread_body + 138
      36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87bc272a _pthread_struct_init + 0
      37  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff87bc6fc9 thread_start + 13
      )
```

It appears NSURLConnection is trying to get the LENGTH of an NSString, but is accidentally trying this with an NSMutableArray object.  Where in the heck in my code am I at fault for this?

In case it matters, this crash occurs about 2 seconds after the initWithRequest call is made.

Can it be something weird in my build environment? For the life of me I can't figure out why this small piece of code would blow up.

Thanks for any help out there in advance.

Comment: It might be that the application name in your Info.plist-file is an array and not a string.

Comment: The stack trace indicates that problem happens while trying to build the user-agent string. Somehow, some component of the user agent string that should be from an `NSString` is actually an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: You are hiding important part of code from us.

Comment: Andy, what code do you want to see?  Also, I lifted this exact code into another application that I've developed and it works fine.  Can you guys elaborate more on the user-agent string?

Comment: OK, you guys are awesome. Somehow (and I have no clue how this happened), my CFBundleName got changed from a string to an array of strings.  Mind is blown!

Comment: Mats, please add an answer containing this suggestion/solution; Chuck, please mark the answer as accepted so Mats gets the credit and the question no longer shows as "unanswered".